# Integrate generated HTML page with Play framework application

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I've a web service generate code of a **complete** HTML, I want to integrate the generated HTML code into the view in my Play framework application. here is code in my controller:

```
public static void showReport(String specification) {
    String[] results= ReportRunner2.generateReport(specification); //call web service
    String output = HTMLUtil.extractBody(results[0]); //output is the complete HTML code
    render(output);
}
```

In my showReport.html:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
${output}
```

It turns out the generated HTML is not correctly rendered because the redundant `<html>` and `<body>` added from template, I've tried remove those tags in main.html but it does not work, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `renderHtml(output)` instead of `render(output)`. No template will be used, just your html.